# When is it appropriate to post a question and answer it right away?

Tags: discussion, self-answer

I realise that it could be helpful to add a question that I know the answer to and post both. Although I have yet to do this I would like to know when and if this is acceptable.

Comment: When you've actually researched whether the information you'd be posting already exists on the site you're posting on would be a good start. (Hint: this is covered in several of the questions already tagged self-answer.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's appropriate whenever you have a question with a answer to which both meet the site's standards for quality, on topic-ness, etc.